# Capture Video in Objective C

Tags: xcode4

I am new to the iPhone development. I would like to know how to capture the video in Xcode....
I know how to take still images in iPhone using Xcode but dont know how to capture video. Can anybody help me??? Any little help will be appreciated greatly. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you mean create a video of a running iPhone application or record video on the device itself?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's no direct way to capture video from a running application in the way that you can grab a screenshot in Xcode.

As such, you *might* want to use some screen recording software in conjunction with the iPhone Simulator.