# AV Video Capture in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

I would like to know what is AVVideoCapture?

Comment: Your question is a bit too generic. You should give more details about what are you trying to do. Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368763/capture-video-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

There were three sessions covering AV Foundation during WWDC 2010 that are available for free through Apple Developer Video Archive:

- *[Discovering AV Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/)* Introduces the Framework and provides a nice overview of its capabilities and design.
- Since you'll probably want to do something with the media you'll eventually capture, you might want to check out *[Editing Media with AV Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/)* as well.
- And finally *[Using the Camera with AV Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/)* is what it says on the bin.

That's about 2:45 h worth of video that should get you up and running.

Did I mention:
**It's free!**